# polish coding in opensagres is not good. What to do?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use

<%@page import="fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter"%>

<%@page import="fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions"%>

Those are dependencies for converting docx to pdf. But code is:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(documentFileName));
OutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(documentPDFFileName));
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("UTF-8");
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out2, options);
```

I am not getting polish characters in pdf even if docx is with polish encoding.
I tried to add PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("UTF-8"). It is still displaying
it wrong or nothing at all.

How to make pdf with polish characters?

Comment: Does the font you're using have those characters? It may not be an encoding issue.

Comment: It has polish characters. It displays well in Word